# In HTML5 WebAudio how to know whether sound was stopped or finished playing?

Tags: javascript, html, events, web-audio-api

I'm trying to create a very simple music player using Web Audio API. One of the requirement is a function that when one track is finished - next one starts automatically.

Currently I'm subscribing for the 'ended' event. Something along the lines with

```
nodeSource.onEnded = function () {}
nodeSource.start(0, offset, duration);
```

The problem comes from the fact that 'onended' is triggered in two cases:

- sound finished playing (exactly what's needed)
- someone actually stopped the sound (not needed at all)

I need a way to separate these two cases. Currently I wasn't able to find a value of current position inside the sound buffer, so I could compare it to the time when sound should end.

I understand that it's possible to create a separate timer at the start of the playback and then check whether the sound is still playing right before it should stop, but that is a really weird way to do it.

Is there a way to get what I need with Web Audio itself? Or, maybe, any other, less weird way?

Comment: How is the user stopping the audio?  Do you have a button that is clicked?  If so, like Raymond Toy mentions, you should be able to decipher between a user instigated "onended" event and when the song is actually finished.

Comment: Yes, there is a button clicked. It seems like the best solution, though I really hoped that there is a way using WebAudio to solve the task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If someone stopped the sound, your program must have known that and stopped the sound.  Before you actually stop the sound, remove the `onended` handler.

Answer (score 0):

All the solutions I've found have had some way of holding a timer, I don't think there is a way around it that's cleaner.

This is a good solution I've found, don't use the stop, write code to pause it.and then you won't activate the trigger

```
function stop() {
    sourceNode.stop(0);
    pausedAt = Date.now() - startedAt;
    paused = true;
};
```

[https://stackoverflow.com/a/18562855/3649914][1]

[1]: Code found here